# Proving that eigenvalues are positive iff $\det(A_k)> 0$ for all $k = 1, ..., n$ for a real symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I am trying to prove that eigenvalues  of $A$ are positive iff $\det(A_k)> 0$ for all $k = 1, ..., n$ for a real symmetric matrix $A$ where $A_k$ is the $k \times k$ matrix obtained by deleting the $(k + 1)$ through $n$ row and columns from $A$ for $n = 2$.

Proving this for $k = 1$ is easy, since $\det(A_1) = a > 0$ for $A_1 = a$. $\det(A_1 - \lambda I_1) = a - \lambda = 0$ therefore $\lambda = a > 0$

I am having some difficulty with $k = 2$

I know that $\det(A_2) = ad - bc > 0$ for $A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
a && b \\
c && d \\
\end{pmatrix}$

and that $\det(A_2 - \lambda I_2) = \lambda(a - d - \lambda) + ad - bc = 0$ but I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues.

Comment: @Timbuc Hmm, but couldn't the eigenvalues be negative and still have a positive determinant?

Comment: This property is fairly standard, see property 3 of [positive-definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties)

Comment: @JorgeCastillo use also that A is symmetric in that case what happens with odd negative eigenvalues ?

Comment: A common approach to this proof is to use the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem).